# Unpredictable person

Tags: single-word-requests

What is an *adjective* that describes a person who is unpredictable in a negative or potentially dangerous way? I keep thinking "volatile," but I'm looking for a word more cohesive with the description of a person rather than a science experiment or something. Perhaps something similar to "loose cannon," but an adjective? I believe I am looking for a specific word, but I can't think of it.

Comment: [Ditzy](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ditzy), though the connotation is not strongly negative.

Comment: How about loose cannon?

Comment: @Nasser I have that in the question; I'm looking for an adjective.

Answer (score 6):

> Unstable
>
> Erratic
>
> Impulsive
>
> Fickle

In order of how negative they are in my opinion. There are a few other less ideal ones, like "iffy" and "capricious", but those are the four I'd consider the most negative/dangerous sounding synonyms for unpredictable in terms of people.

Comment: I rather like "capricious" here. It feels quite dangerous to me.

Answer (score 5):

[Volatile](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/volatile) is a very good word, not at all necessarily scientific, but connotes explosive.

> - liable to change rapidly and unpredictably, especially for the worse.
> - (of persons) disposed to caprice or inconstancy; fickle; mercurial  (Collins/TFD)

A clinical word for this is [labile](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/labile):

> Open to change; readily changeable or unstable (TFD)

For example,

> Emotional Dysregulation is also referred to as *labile mood* (a marked fluctuation of mood) or mood swings.

Comment: I think mercurial is actually close... for some reason I just think there is another word better than volatile.

Comment: "Labile" is excellent. We could probably find a bushel of equivalents in the DSM-V, e.g., "bipolar."

Answer (score 4):

Many good words have been suggested. You could also consider using the adjective [**mercurial**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/mercurial) which means:

> Subject to sudden or unpredictable changes of mood or mind: '*his
>   mercurial temperament*'.

More broadly used one is [**capricious**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/capricious):

> Given to sudden and unaccountable changes of mood or behaviour

[Oxford Online Dictionary]

Answer (score 1):

Several synonyms have been suggested; considering that you specified:

> I believe I am looking for a specific word, but I can't think of it.

I thought I would point out a few words that are more similar in *sound* to "volatile" than the excellent words so far suggested, and that are at least somewhat similar in meaning as well (or at least related).  Hopefully one of these may jog your memory:

- vacillating
- vindictive
- virulent
- vitriolic

And, some more common words I found during my search that I think are unlikely to be the word you are looking for, but *might* be:

- variable
- vicious
- violent

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the above list:

Whimsical

Wayward

Impulsive

Fluky

Dicey

Waggish

Wiggly

Wobbly

Arbitrary

Chimerical

Quicksilver

Fickle.

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage. It is not encouraged to post an answer without any research/reference/link that can support it. Please edit your answer after taking the [tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and visiting our [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for additional guidance. Please select a few of them and add dictionary definitions.